# Json MissingMemberHandling when using converters

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Deserializing a saved interface object using Json.NET without defining it's implementation type was throwing errors (of course) so I wrote a re-usable class:

```
public class MakeJsonConverter<TParent, TChild> : JsonConverter where TChild:TParent
{
    private readonly Type _parent;
    private Type _child;

    public MakeJsonConverter()
    {
        _parent = typeof(TParent);
        _child = typeof(TChild);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == _parent);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TChild>(reader);
    }

    //This should never be called. Only reading from saved interface data was an issue without using a converter.
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It works fine, except for the fact that the settings I pass to it don't seem to be used. Actually I don't know that for sure, what I do know is that MissingMemberHandling.Error isn't working.

```
public virtual string SerializeWithConverter<TParent, TChild>(TParent obj) where TChild : TParent
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            DefaultMembersSearchFlags =
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
        },
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
        ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,

        //Settings important to this situation
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new MakeJsonConverter<TParent, TChild>() }
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, settings);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is working the way it is.. can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All when serializing and deserializing

This might help the deserializer in case you have nested objects structures which you want to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you say MissingMemberHandling.Error isn't working?
I'm assuming it's because you are expecting an error when a user over/under posts an object that doesn't match your object? Either way, I believe the MissingMemberHandling.Error won't throw when you set your own custom ContractResolver. Instead, create your own class that inherits from DefaultContractResolver and override the JsonObjectContract. This will provide a result similar to what you are expecting.

```
    public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            contract.ItemRequired = Required.Always;
            return contract;
        }
    }
```

Then use that as your contract resolver

```
ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(),
```

Tested and worked for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11274695)

Comment: @wogsland I expanded my answer with an example.